# Has anybody ever done large searches in JavaScript using webworkers to parallelize?

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, web-worker

I'm writing a search function in JavaScript which is highly parallelizable, and operates on enormous data sets. The data sets are stored in trees of JS objects, and it could be implemented by partitioning the search into web workers.

Is anybody aware of products and/or research doing similar things? I'd like to read some experience going too far down the implementation path, but Googling has been totally unhelpful.

Comment: The question is very broad. You can improve it by talking about what you've tried. SO is for answerable questions. Changing the question to "What are some examples of parallelization using WebWorkers" makes it easier to answer. Otherwise, I would list what you've tried so far and list your concerns.

Comment: for me, the only browser where WebWorkers gave the advertised speed up was ie10 pp2 and above... but in any case - you cannot get the number of cpu cores, thus you will either need to blindly assume that cpu has 8 cores (or other magic number), or create some kind of test.. to determine number of cores, and then splitting your code to this number of workers ... anyway - you'll probably be the pioneer in this area. But consider reading about Intel's project [Rivertrail](http://blogs.intel.com/research/2011/09/15/pjs/).

Comment: Is there a specific reason this needs to be done in JavaScript? Even with WebWorkers you wont truly achieve parallization, best to do the heavy lifting on the server and deliver the result to the browser (if possible)

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't really an "answer", but here's some useful reading if you haven't already discovered it on your own:

- [Stack Overflow #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907593/parallel-processing-simulation-in-javascript)
- [Stack Overflow #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057284/javascript-parallelism)
- [Intel Article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/17/intel_parallel_javascript/)